# Pressing Enter/Return key doesn't trigger button click in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, safari

I have a structure of the following format , which I display in a Bootstrap modal.

```
<div>
 <input type="text"/>
 <input type="text"/>
 <button class="jSomeButton" onclick="javascript: return false;"></button>
 <!--Click event handled in Javascript code-->
</div>

$(function(){
   $(".jSomeButton").on('click',function(){
      //Called from Firefox, Chrome and IE
      //Not called from Safari
   });
});
```

In Firefox, Chrome and IE when I press Enter/Return key after filling the inputs, the button click is triggered.
But in Safari [v4.0.3] , it doesn't trigger the button click! Rather it seems to postback to the same page.

Is this a known issue in Safari?
If yes, any workaround?
If no, could someone please help me with figuring out the root problem?

P.S. :
1. I'm familiar with the Javascript code for triggering button click on Enter keypress event. Just curious as to why the above won't work *only* in Safari.
2.Just for clarification, pressing Enter key while I'm still on the input control and not by pressing tab to first focus on the button and then press Enter.

Comment: Can you share your whole code with us so we can help ?

Comment: @DevangRathod : Do you mean the entire mark-up? What else do you need to know?

Comment: means actullay what you want result ?

Comment: i have posted my answer so please try and let me know.

Comment: @Vandesh, I think every set of inputs you have should have a form around it, and one of the buttons should have an action type submit. In that case pressing enter on any input field should initiate the button click. Also, I tried the exact code , works for me in Safari. (Windows.)

Comment: @All : seems to be a browser issue. 
Works fine on Safari v5.x but not on v4.x
Thanks for all your help. Appreciate it.
Will try n dig more into the problem with 4.x

Answer (score 3):

Add the input fields and buttons to a form.

try using this but i m not sure about this is the right way to do it.
in that case you better add two js listener functions to the input fields. as

`

```
  <div>
     <input id="one" type="text"/>
     <input id="two" type="text"/>
     <button class="jSomeButton" onclick="javascript: return false;">               </button>
     <!--Click event handled in Javascript code-->
    </div>



$('#one').keypress(function(e){
if(e.which == 13) {
//call your code

 }
});

$('#two').keypress(function(e){
if(e.which == 13) {
///call your code
 }
});
```

better you write three listeners one for button other two for two input files. hope this ill help you. i am not sure about this solution. please let me know after trying it.

Comment: Doesn't look like a very clean solution.

Comment: Anyways, the issue is getting it to work with Safari version 4.x I think.

Comment: if so ignore using <button> and use <input type="submit" value="Submit">

Answer (score 0):

Instead of class attribute use id attribute onclick event ,

```
<div>
 <input type="text"/>
 <input type="text"/>
 <button class="jSomeButton" id="jSomeButton" onclick="javascript: return false;"></button>
 <!--Click event handled in Javascript code-->
</div>


$(function(){
   $("#jSomeButton").on('click',function(){
      //Called from Firefox, Chrome and IE
      //Not called from Safari
   });
});
```

if you do not want to add `ID` you can `delegate` event to the `document` so event will work on `DOM` which has defined class.

**Example**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', ".jSomeButton" ,function(){
        alert('works');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: @Vandesh Yes i have checked it working condition..please also see edit that will make point more clear.

Comment: @Vandesh have you checked ?

Comment: nopes. Doesn't work for me. Any logical explanation as to why this works for you (in Safari) and the previous one does not?

Answer (score 0):

@Vandesh,

As posted in comments, I suggest you put up a form tag around your entire form.
Have a look at this JSFiddle for more idea.

http://jsfiddle.net/JUryD/

I tried this on Safari, Chrome, IE6+, Opera and Firefox 22+

Let me know if you face any other troubles.

Here is the code:

```
<div>
 <form>            
  <input type="text"/>
  <input type="text"/>
  <button class="jSomeButton" onclick="javascript: return false;">Send</button>  
 </form>
</div>
```

Comment: checked the fiddle in Safari v4.0.3 . Doesn't work. What was the version you tried on?